# linear regression with massive data

Tags: regression

Assume I have a data set, N sample entries with P factors for each and I would like to run a linear regression. Assume one of the variables is categorical with large K possibilities of the values it takes. I have seen statements "Linear Regression doesn't do well on massive datasets" but I want to clarify what it actually means in each case:

Case 1: N is very large but P and K are moderate(is there a golden rule when we say "too many" factors? I don't know). That is, lots of data samples, thus I can cross validate and do lots of fitting on different parts of the dataset. Could there be an issue with too many observations? How does it hurt?

Case 2: N is small but P is large, and most importantly K is large(it is categorical so it adds K new variables to already existing P-1 and makes lots of X_i factors). I assume this is bad because the model is prone to overfit given large complexity? Is that an issue? Can I do AIC comparison on it to remove some features? Could I do something clever with my categorical variable?

Case 3: Both N, P and K are large. I assume problems from 1 and 2 apply here. What are the steps to be taken immediately to remedy those problems to some extent?

Comment: Where did you read that linear regression doesn't do well on massive datasets? Depending on what is meant, I vehemently disagree.

Comment: @Dave I have been reading a book "Machine Learning and Data Science Blueprints for Finance" and it stated as "Linear and logistic Regression are not able to handle large datasets and large number of features well". But then it will go into the benefits of ANN, CART and ensemble methods that do. Perhaps I am not clear on that statement and I wanted to clarify. I am sure one can take some steps to have regression perform well but what are the issues with each to begin with?

Comment: With a large dataset, you are more likely to be able to estimate a complicated model well so that linear regression performs worse than the complicated model. However, even without taking special steps, you would expect linear regression trained on a large dataset to perform better (across any measure of model quality I can think of) than linear regression trained on a small dataset drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: @jkpate: right, that addresses 1, the more the training data, the more tools we have, so I would think the large data set is referred as having too many samples. Meaning you don't have enough memory to store it, but even in that case I can simply use a randomly selected subset and train any model I like. The bigger question is then what's wrong with 2?